# com.facebook.sdk error 2 in distribution

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I already had this working in older versions of my app but our newest update shows this error: com.facebook.sdk error 2 when logging in to facebook.
The app works fine in the simulator and device when built in development mode but the error only shows up when its in the App Store and built in distribution mode. I already found tons of information on the internet but thats not working.

I've checked:

- sandbox mode is disabled
- bundle id is correct
- app store id is correct
- facebook logging and deep linking are enabled?

Again our older version worked fine in distribution mode. Our newest version of our app uses facebook sdk 3.5.

**EDIT**

I unlinked facebook on my device and found out that it returns the wrong app! When pressing the login button safari opens up ask the user for permissions then returns to another app I made (practically the same app but made for a different company). So I deleted all apps on my device and the error was gone.
Double checked the app id on developers.facebook.com and the fbid in my code and thats all correct.

Why is my app returning a different app after giving permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason my phone was mixing up my apps. Uninstalled all and reinstalled and everything worked out fine.